# Report viewer tag missing in toolbox Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015

I recently installed Visual Studio 2015 Community and now my toolbox does not have the report viewer tag, all my existing report viewers in my ASP.NET project show 'error creating Control'. I've checked all my references and they seem to be OK, when I Run the project the report appears fine in the browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From reading this, you need to add the SQL Server Data Tools package.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/70e6b312-48b6-48f5-abc7-6400dfe8ad34/visual-studio-2015-enterprise-reporting-functionality-missing?forum=vssetup

We have managed to track down the solution to this issue. It turns out that the components required for reporting are located within the Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools package. In order to install this package, perform the following steps as a privileged (local or domain administrator) account. Ensure that Visual Studio and all related programs are closed before you begin.

Open Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features, and select the entry for your version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. In our case, it was Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.
Click the "Change" button on the top bar above the program list.
After the splash screen, a window will open. Press the "Modify" button.
Select Windows and Web Development > Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, and check the box next to it.
Press the "Update" button on the lower-right hand side of the window.
Once the installation is complete, open your version of Visual Studio. After the new .dll files are loaded, Reporting functionality should be reimplemented, and you should be able to access all related forms, controls, and objects.
Our working theory is that the web installer did not install the required components for Reporting during the initial installation - however, the issue seems to be resolved now.

Comment: Thanks i managed to do that and it worked fine....works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up for VS 2017. The control is no longer located in the "Toolbox" but is now instead a NuGet package. It can be installed via the Package Manager Console with the command: 
`Install-Package ReportViewerForMvc`

See: https://reportviewerformvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation%20%26%20configuration