# There's no ReportViewer in Toolbox. How to add it on a panel?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Actual screenshot

[image]

I need to create a report for a dataset. I've got `DataGridViev` containing stuff from DataSet(table).

I need to create a Report. On Internet is told to add ReportViewer to do this. I can't add ReportViewer that looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: whats your question?explain more...your question body must have explain more about your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Report viewer tag missing in toolbox Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897493/report-viewer-tag-missing-in-toolbox-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this steps to add the Report Viewer on your Toolbox, since components on reporting are located within Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools Package:

1. Open Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features
2. Choose the version of your Visual Studio, in my case, Visual Studio 2015 (Enterprise)
3. Click the Change button on the upper side.
4. Once the setup screen opens, press the Modify button
5. Select Windows and Web Development -> Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools and check the box next to it.
6. Click the Update button afterwards. Once the installation is complete restart your Visual Studio and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

1st I removed all references to Report Viewer in my References and went to my packages folder in my application and removed all report view files from there.  I also opened up packages,config in VS 2017 (with the project closed) and removed all references to Report Viewer from there and saved the file.

I then reopened my project and with nuget, installed the new report viewer and then closed the project.  Then I went to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SqlReportingServices.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001 and installed the new report designer.   When I opened the project, I could go to the toolbox, right click on it and left click on choose items.    Click on browse and double click on the application, then double click on packages, double click on Microsoft.ReportingServices.REportViewer Control.Winforms.140.340.80 (as update may be higher number), then double click on lib and double click on net40.   Then double click on Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll.    Process is the same for webforms.  This worked.
I built a new tab called Reports and moved the Report viewer to that tab.